# JQuery Drag and Drop - Big Connected Lists with Fixed Height

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I am struggling with a problem for quite sometime now, maybe somebody has an idea :)

I have two big lists arranged vertically, and I just want to drag and drop items between the two lists. Since my lists are big, I gave them a limited height with `overflow: auto` value. To render the dragged items, I used the `appendTo: document.body` and `helper: clone` sortable properties.

My problem is that although my ul height are fixed, the li elements are not and those from the top list overlap those from the bottom list. This prevent dropping elements in the bottom list to work properly.

I created a jsfiddle reproducing my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/ETGyq/27/
Does anybody have an idea how I could fix my problem ?
I tried playing with the sortable properties or the CSS but I couldn't find any nice solution...

Thanks a lot,
Antoine